# How to handle an Entity in JPA with Single Instance?

Tags: java, jpa

Hi Im new to JPA I want to know how to handle the following scenario

I need to maintain in database the total count of messages received, there is no need to store messages but only its count.Im representing count by an Entity called MessageCount having a variable count as follows

```
    @Entity  
    public class MessageCount  
    {  
        long count;
    ...
```

I need to update count whenever i recieve a message.

How can i update it ?
What will be the correct approach to handle this ?

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to reliably (read: atomically) do this is to issue a direct query (as opposed to fetching the entity and incrementing it). The appropriate JPA query would be:

```
UPDATE MessageCount SET count = count + 1
```

If you fetch the entity with JPA, add 1, and save it again - you risk overwriting the value that another thread has incremented and saved. Performing the operation in a single query ensures that it happens in a single, atomic transaction.

Comment: Thanks,but i cant justify using JPA here because i can instead use direct mysql connection and do this(no need for entity class and all those stuff)

Comment: If your application is using JPA for other things anyway, you're better off sticking with JPA. Right now, it's abstracting away your underlying database implementation. There's an _extremely minimal_ cost associated with using JPA for this if it's already in use. However, I wouldn't recommend _adding_ JPA for this purpose.